# Is the Amputator taunt useful?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-medic

I recently crafted the [Amputator](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Amputator), mainly for the [set bonus](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Medieval_Medic).  I've tested the taunt and it certainly seems to heal people, but is it really useful when you have unlimited healing with the medi-gun?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the Amputator taunt is useful. You can use the *Medi Gun* to heal people individually and get your ÜberCharge up, but you can save a lot of people's lives with the Amputator taunt.

For example, if a Pyro charges at a group that you are healing one-by-one and burns a lot of them, you might not be able to extinguish everyone before they die. The Amputator taunt will help in this scenario by quickly extinguishing all your teammates at once leaving no one behind.

I personally love the Amputator because it helps a lot of people especially when there are a lot of needy people who want you all to themselves. Using the Amputator taunt you can share the love.

You can read more about the taunt [here.](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Medicating_Melody)

Here's a quick comparison of healing methods:

```
                   Heals*  Healee  Duration  Charges**
Oktoberfest         11       Self      4  s     0
Medicating Melody   25       Team      4.2s     0
                    (if in sight and range)

Medigun             24/s   Target        -   2.5 %/s
Kritzkrieg          24/s   Target        -   3.13%/s
QuickFix (beta)     36/s   Target        -   3.75%/s

*  300% for targets that haven't received damage in the last 3 seconds
**  50% for targets that are at 142.5% health or higher
```

Comment: The Amputator makes you an open target for enemy Snipers and Spies.

Comment: You can always find a little area that is covered from snipers and hope that the teammates that you are healing will protect the area from spies. You can also look around the area while taunting to look for spies.

Comment: You would have to have several teammates very close to death for the taunt to be preferable to just quickly spreading the medigun healing around. Since it is essentially impossible to have such detailed information on teammate health available at a moment's notice, I would say that it is *never* preferable from a practical standpoint. As mentioned in the other answer, the only reason to use the amputator taunt is in Degroot Keep.

Answer (score 15):

The Amputator's taunt allows you to heal multiple people at once. Of course, the drawback is that you're standing still and open to attack when you do it.

The Amputator works well on `cp_degrootkeep` (Medieval Mode), where you're not allowed to use your medi-guns, and the small size of the map means players are bunched closer together.